# jQuery(...).plugin is not a function because js file is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I use a plugin (in this example it is selectric). I only load the plugin javascript file on product pages.

The code I use is: `jQuery('.myselectpicker').selectric({});` and is located in a custom javascript file witch is loaded on every page.

If I go to an other page then the product page, I get a `jQuery(...).selectric is not a function` error.

I understand why I get the error, because the plugin javascript file is not included in the head (only on product pages).

But is there something I can put around the `jQuery('.myselectpicker').selectric({});`  code so it doesn't return an error on other pages than the product page?
I don't want to add the code to the plugin javscript file or in a seperate javascript file only loaded on the product page.
And for performance reasons I don't want to include all javascript files on every page type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery's `isFunction` function - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/

```
// Will trigger selectric() function only if it's lib included
if( $.isFunction( $.fn.selectric ) ){
    jQuery('.myselectpicker').selectric({});
}
```

Comment: Thanx that was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know about the `isFunction` function.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to check if `selectric` is loaded is to check if any elements on your page need it, ie:

```
if (jQuery('.myselectpicker').length > 0)
    jQuery('.myselectpicker').selectric({});
```

this will then give an error - so could be combined with `isFunction` (see other answer, no need to repeat here) - but, will let you know which pages need the plugin but are missing it, rather than just missing functionality without warning.